# How can I choose AMD graphics card as default for Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: graphics, xorg, amd-graphics, xorg.conf

### Context

I have spend some time solving this and now I am stuck. When I inspect output of `lspci`, I find that I have two possible VGA controlers:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Whistler [Radeon HD 6730M/6770M/7690M XT] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
```

Only the default Intel processor graphics seem to be chosen now. This is also confirmed by running `lshw -c display`, which gives:

```
*-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 09
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:36 memory:c0000000-c03fffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:6000(size=64)
```

### Now to the problem

This is why I decided to try and create custom xorg.conf file in the system in order to be able to asign the graphics card to the display directly. But, when I start Ubuntu with this file in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`, I get an error which I do not know how to resolve.

The contents of the file are:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "amd-layout"
    Screen 0 "amd-screen" 0 0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "amd-device"
    Driver "radeon"
    BusID "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "intel"
    Option "AccelMethod" "uxa"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "amd-monitor"
    Option "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "amd-screen"
    Device "amd-device"
    GPUDevice "intel"
    Monitor "amd-monitor"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

The reading from `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` of the error is:

```
[    41.323] (EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
[    41.323] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[    41.323] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[    41.323] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
  at http://wiki.x.org
  for help. 
[    41.323] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[    41.323] (EE) 
[    41.326] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

I have a feeling that I probably messed up when creating the `xorg.conf` file, but I do not know where? Do you see a mistake there?

Comment: UPDATE: I found out that the problem why screen was not loading was because radeon driver could not find any modes (Error in Xorg.o.log read: "RADEON(0): No modes"). I tried a workaround solution when I found on [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/688388/14-04-gets-black-screen-unless-radeon-modeset-0), but even though the system started, the performance was worse than before. I am trying to figure out how to solve this now.