# Boot iMac to Terminal

Tags: boot, display

I'm trying to fix the display problem on an older iMac (2009) that is discussed in this link: [14.04 gets black screen unless radeon.modeset=0](https://askubuntu.com/questions/688388/14-04-gets-black-screen-unless-radeon-modeset-0)

But, I cannot figure out how to boot my iMac to a terminal window.  Instead I always get the dead screen.

How do I boot to a terminal prompt that I can see?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using the option button to boot back to the USB installation stick.  Then I modified the file one edits from grub by adding `nomodeset` to the `linux` line.